# Heroku messed up with my Socket.Io / NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a website but when I try to log in I always get the '**Invalid enpoint**' that I've created. While running it in my computer the app works perfect. And it used to work perfectly before I implemented socket.io, so I'm probably messing up something on my front-end.

Here is my **app.js** code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
const client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;


dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
PRIVATE INFO
});    

const users = require('./routes/users');
const info = require('./routes/info');


app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:4200'}));

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/info', info)


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Invalid endpoint");
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
const host = '0.0.0.0';
app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on: " + port)
});


// Device IoT
var device = awsIot.device({
PRIVATE CONFIG, SORRY
  });

device
.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Works');
    device.subscribe('PRIVATE-BUT-WORKING');
});

client.on('connection', function(socket){
  device.on('message', function(topic, payload) {
      socket.emit('output', payload.toString());
  });
});
```

Here's the **service** I use with the socket:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class SocketIOService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:8080';
    private socket;

    getMessages() {
        let observable = new Observable(observer => {
          this.socket = io(this.url);
          this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
            observer.next(data);
          });
          return () => {
            this.socket.disconnect();
          };
        })
        return observable;
      }
}
```

I tried with some solutions I've found here but nothing happens

Comment: Why is the socket service hitting http://localhost:8080' ???

Comment: Because that's where it works when I run the app on my computer. I'm not sure what should I put there.

Comment: What port is your socket server listening on locally? 8888 is your default, do you pass in something on the environment?

Comment: Mmmm... I don't think so. Locally I don't do anything, I just run the nodejs server and everything works fine.

Comment: You will have to explicitly point to the socket server. This is a duplicate. I will show you where the answer is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.io and Node.js not working on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210816/socket-io-and-node-js-not-working-on-heroku)

Comment: Nope. That didn't solved my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  The most serious one is that you trying to serve websockets over a different port than your express app.  Heroku only opens one port for a web dyno.  So you need to do something like this on the server side (adapted from the socket.io) docs:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(port);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

From there you can edit your client to hit against the right server (this should work both locally and remotely). You should be able to construct the socket client without any argument (which will tell it to connect to the origin):

```
this.socket = io();
```

There's also probably something wrong with your cors setup.

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:4200'}));
```

Is that origin ever going to be in play?  But maybe you can fix whatever problems that causes after you fix these other things.